# will server retransmit an ACK packet?

Tags: tcp, retransmit-timeout

A tcp connection has a client and a server, my question is will the server start a timer when it sends an ACK packet to the client? and will the server retransmit that ACK packet if the packet gets timeout or lost?

Answer (score 0):

> will the server start a timer when it sends an ACK packet to the client?

The server will not control if the ACK was received by the client. If the client does not receive an ACK for transmitted data it will assume that either the data or the ACK to the data got lost. In this case it will simply resend the unacknowledged data - which will result in the server sending another ACK for the same data.